# ES search without wildcards not getting results with analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

After reading the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) and some Q&A here I still can't get my Elasticsearch to properly search for partial words without wildcards.

I've got ~470k entries of companies and want to accomplish some kind of autocompletion when starting to enter a company name.

the index gets created like this:

```
{
  "lei-index" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "record" : {
        "properties" : {
          "LegalName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "legalname_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer" : "legalname_search"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "provided_name" : "lei-index",
        "creation_date" : "1478597987141",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "legalname_filter" : {
              "type" : "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram" : "4",
              "max_gram" : "20"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "legalname_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "legalname_filter",
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "legalname_tokenizer"
            },
            "legalname_search" : {
              "filter" : [
                "legalname_filter",
                "standard",
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "legalname_tokenizer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer" : {
            "legalname_tokenizer" : {
              "token_chars" : [
                "letter"
              ],
              "min_gram" : "4",
              "type" : "edge_ngram",
              "max_gram" : "20"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "mUBvjn9BSBayrkvXSIXxQw",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "5000051"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I know look for lets say Hapag-Loyd, I can search for "Hapag" and get 3 results for "hapag loyd", "hapag-loyd", and "hapag loyd"

But I want to archive that I can search for "hapa" and already get the results.

http://localhost:9200/lei-index/record/_search?pretty&q=hapa

0 results

With a wildcard I get results, including hapag loyd, but I guess wildcards are inefficient in larger indexes

http://localhost:9200/lei-index/record/_search?pretty&q=hapa*

I tried to use keywords as tokenizer and leaving the filter out and just use the tokenizer but didn't get the expected results.

Testing the analyzer:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/lei-index/_analyze?pretty' -d '{ "analyzer": "legalname_analyzer", "text": "hapag"}'
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "hapa",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "hapa",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "hapag",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Would be great if anyone could point out where my thinking goes wrong here, since it's the first time I work with elasticsearch.

And one last thing, I've got nothing to do with hapag-loyd, I just used it as an example here.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to specify the field name as well, so the proper analyzers kick in at search time? `http://localhost:9200/lei-index/record/_search?pretty&q=LegalName:hapa`

Comment: Darn!! of course I hadn't .... Can you post this as an answer ? And thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making the following request, the standard analyzer for the `query_string` query kicks in.

```
http://localhost:9200/lei-index/record/_search?pretty&q=hapa
```

That's not what you want. Instead, you need to specify your `LegalName` field so the `search_analyzer` for that field is leveraged:

```
http://localhost:9200/lei-index/record/_search?pretty&q=LegalName:hapa
```

Another solution is to keep your query but override the standard analyzer of the query string with your own one:

```
http://localhost:9200/lei-index/record/_search?pretty&q=hapa&analyzer=legalname_search
```

Comment: http://localhost:9200/lei-index/record/_search?pretty&q=hapa&analyzer=legalname_analyzer

Doesn't seem to work, but specifying the field, does. Thanks

Comment: make sure to surround the whole query including the query string within single quotes, otherwise the `&` character will get misinterpreted